# Question of Multivariable Limits

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I came across this ([Limit of a function $\frac{f}{n}$ as n goes to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498607/limit-of-a-function-fracfn-as-n-goes-to-infinity)) recently asked question and was wondering about the limit . I have just completed high school and already studied limits(for single variable) in High School,so I thought I might be able to answer this.

After pondering over the question for nearly half an hour,I thought I would check what the online calculators say.
[image]

But,the results left me more confused than before because I had expected that if $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(\infty,\infty)} \frac{e^{x^2}}{y}=0$,

then so should $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(\infty,\infty)}$ $\frac{e^{x}}{y}$
as  $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} {e^{x^2}}$ >$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} {e^{x}}$  .

Maybe I am missing something obvious but I am not able to see anything wrong in my thinking currently.

Thanks.

Comment: I have doubt in left result - where did you get it? Try, for example, $y=x$ and, obviously, it is not $0$.

Comment: @zkutch I tried here https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=2958433016861a528d6221f5ac88eefd

Comment: Sorry, but it is mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the limit as $(x, y)\to\infty$ in $\mathbb R^2$ means studying the behaviour of a function as $|(x, y)|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\to\infty$; a neighbourhood of $\infty$ in $\mathbb R^2$ is the complement of a ball. Notice that for $(x, y)\to\infty$ you don't need both $x\to\infty$ and $y\to\infty$.

You can actually consider several different limits that correspond to particular paths that approach infinity:
$$\lim_{y\to+\infty} f(0, y)=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{1}{y}=0,$$
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x,1)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^{x^2}=+\infty,$$

but also:

$$\lim_{y\to+\infty}\left(\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{y}\right)=+\infty$$
$$\lim_{y\to-\infty}\left(\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{y}\right)=-\infty$$
$$\lim_{y\to+\infty}\left(\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{y}\right)=+\infty$$
$$\lim_{y\to-\infty}\left(\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{y}\right)=-\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{y}\right)= \lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\lim_{y\to-\infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{y}\right)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{y}\right)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\lim_{y\to-\infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{y}\right)=0.$$

As you can see, the order of the limits does influence the result, so taking "$\lim_{(x, y)\to(\infty, \infty)}$" does not make sense in this case. The fact that different paths give us different limits tells us that the the $\lim_{(x, y)\to\infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{y}$ does not exist. If you think about it geometrically, in multivariate calculus you have many more directions and paths to approach a point (or infinity), so, even more than in univariate calculus, the existence of a limit is a rare condition, and proving the existence of a limit is harder. When trying to evaluate a limit to $\infty$ in $\mathbb R^2$, first check if you can easily prove that is does not exist by taking the limit along some simple paths, for example $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x, 0)$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x, x)$, $\lim_{y\to\infty}f(0, y)$, and so on. If you can show that two such limits are not equal (or one of them does not exist), you are done: the original limit does not exist. If all of them exist and are equal, then the original limit might exist, and the only possible value is the one you have already calculated in your previous trials.